# Resetting root password for mariadb does not work

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to reset the root password for a mariadb database, followed every variation of tutorial to do so I've found so far, and every time I try to log in with the new password, it does not accept it.

Mainly, this is what I've been doing:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root -e 'use mysql; update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD("jkjkjkjjk"); flush privileges;'
```

I also tried adding an additional `flush privileges;` before the `udpate` command, removing it from the end as well, different variations for reset password, such as `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');`

I am using mariadb with galera, running on kubernetes statefulset, if relevant.
version of mariadb is `mysqld 10.3.21-MariaDB-1:10.3.21+maria~bionic`

I am incredibly frustrated about this.

Comment: arch specific [how to](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MariaDB#Reset_the_root_password), did you stop the service first before running `mysqld_safe` ?.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is the following:

stop the mysql service with something like:

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
```

then restart it

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

login without a password

```
mysql -u root
```

update the password

```
use mysql;
 update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD("password") WHERE USER='root';
 flush privileges;
 exit
```

restart the db normally

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

This assuming you are using a linux machine and you have access to the shell.
**Note that in your update query you are also missing the where clause so that you are updating ALL your users with the same password!**

**UPDATE 2022 - in case you face error 1348 "password is not updatable"**

The solutions for MySQL Error1348
So you can not update a user password using Update commands, to update the password, use ALTER commands instead. like the following.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

And then you need to do the flush privileges to commit previous queries (that alter command above) into the system, simply do like this.

```
flush privileges;
```

So now you have your root with password 1234.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have done exactly that, and it didn't work. Any ideas on why? The query says it executed successfully

Comment: did you see my note in bold? you miss the where clause on the query. Did you also restarted the mysql instance after?

Comment: I saw that, it was one of my previous variations but I tried it again just in case. I did restart it, though in a slightly different way since I'm using kubernetes and there is no systemd in the container

Comment: The thing is, after performing the above, even if I try to log in using the new password while still in safe mode, it does not accept it

Comment: and I just noticed this: `MariaDB [mysql]> select * from user; 
Empty set (0.000 sec)`

Comment: if you have no users in the table then the query will update nothing at all but will obviously be successfull. if you login in safe mode you have to do it without the password because what happens in safe mode is that it doesn't check the user table (simplyfing)

Comment: @TomKlino If you have no users in the `mysql.user` table you have to add users with the `CREATE USER` command, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-accounts.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. The issue was in fact that the `user` table was empty. I don't know why this happened but I recreated it form our template and then reset the password. That fixed things

Comment: I tried this, but mariadb gives me an error that 'password' is not updateable.

Comment: Yes, [that's right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o/64841540#64841540).