# How to reset password for root in MariaDB 10.5.5-MariaDB on CentOS 8?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos8

I tried the suggestions in [Resetting root password for mariadb does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426812/resetting-root-password-for-mariadb-does-not-work)

[ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) only talks about Ubuntu, not centos 8

Was able to login with `mysql -u root` but there was no user `root` in `mysql` table!!

So, the `set password` statement executes with `0 affected rows.`

Did not work even after server restart.

Comment: Am able to login as a normal user with password

Comment: try this one but read also the answer https://superuser.com/questions/949496/cant-reset-mysql-mariadb-root-password

Comment: If you are using arch, but google still leads you here, try [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MariaDB#Reset_the_root_password) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Login to centos server from ssh. Then stop mysqld service and run mysqld_safe with —skip-grant-tables option to be in insecure mode and to reset the password. Then login to mysql server using mysql command without any -u or -p parameter as you are in insecure mode. Then update the root password flush privilage then exit from msyql console. Then use mysqladmin to stop mysql server which will ask for password give recently saved new password. Then finally start the mysqld service.

```
$ systemctl stop mysqld
$ mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
$ mysql
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;
$ mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
$ systemctl start mysqld
```

Edit: ---------------------------------------

```
$ sudo systemctl stop mariadb
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
$ mysql -u root
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
MariaDB [(none)]>  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
MariaDB [(none)]> exit;
$ sudo kill `/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid`
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

Comment: Failed at step 7

[root@gaze ~]# mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
Enter password:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
[root@gaze ~]#

Comment: skip that step and start mysqld service again i.e. run last command systemctl start mysqld

Comment: [root@gaze ~]# systemctl start mysqld

Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@gaze ~]#

Comment: Even though there was error starting mysqld, I was still able to login as a standard user!

[root@gaze ~]# mysql -u server -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 112
Server version: 10.5.5-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>

Comment: Try using systemctl stop mariadb or service mysqld stop and then start it again

Comment: systecmctl stop/start did not work: Restarted the VPS.

Could not login with new password as root after restart

Comment: what command do you use to start mariadb service is it service mysqld start or systemctl. First you need to stop the server and check its status like (systemctl status mariadb or mysql) then run mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & and update password then restart the service

Comment: I used systemctl.

Comment: I did exactly as outlined in your answer

Comment: Then i will change the above commands please keep track

Comment: hey @Bislinks Dotcom will you please try the edited version of the command in my answer added as edit right now.

Comment: please take a note that i had made a small mistake on the first command. i wrongly typed systemctl stop mysqld instead of systemctl stop mariadb. other commands are okey

Comment: MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPass';

ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
MariaDB [(none)]>

Comment: I used `systemctl stop mariadb`

Comment: use sudo kill `/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid` first then run ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPass' if you are still unable to use alter user then use UPDATE mysql.user SET password = PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User = 'root' ;

Comment: `[root@gaze ~]# kill /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
-bash: kill: /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid: arguments must be process or job IDs
[root@gaze ~]#
`

Comment: are you on team viewer! if yes i will like to help you with remote connection .

Comment: No.  I don't want to do Team Viewer.

Comment: ok then follow through these two tutorial https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-reset-a-mysql-root-password/ and https://robbinespu.github.io/eng/2018/03/29/Reset_mariadb_root_password.html. I hope you get your job done. Thank you!

Comment: I already saw the github post before posting this question. Did not help